How to prevent "auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale' between the filter..." within the filter_complex?
I'm using filter_complex string with vulkan(by hwupload and download).
FFmpeg keep saying that "auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale' between the filter..." and doing something I didn't indicate.
How to prevent get rid out the auto-scaling job within filter_complex?
(What I know is '-noautoscaling' option, but not working for filter_complex)
